# Python: Extracting Text from Applications?

Tags: python, text, extract

I spend each month a lot of time extracting numbers from an application into an Excel-spreadsheet where our company saves numbers, prices, etc. This application is not open-source or so, so unfortunately, sharing the link might not help.

Now, I was wondering whether I could write a Python program that would do this for me instead? But I'm not sure how to do this, particularly the part with extracting the numbers. Once this is done, transfering this to an Excel spreadsheet is particularly trivial.

Answer (score 0):

1)For this you can create a general function like getApplicationError(),
2)in this method you can get the text of the Application Error(create xpath of the application error, and check that if that element is visible than get text) and throw an exception to terminate the Script and you can send that got message into Exception constructor and print that message with Exception.

As you are creating this method for general use so you need to call this method every posible place from where the chances are to get Application Error. like just after click(Create,Save,Submit,Delet,Edit, also just entering value in mendatory Fields)

Comment: Thanks for your answer so far! How exactly does "create xpath of the application error" work? If you could share a link, I would appreciate it very much.